# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator while using IN operator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `col` where i have:

```
select * from offc.col;
```

[image]

I returned some data using query by year wise ans dept_id wise:

```
 SELECT dept_id, 
       year, 
       Max(marks) marks 
FROM   offc.col 
GROUP  BY dept_id, 
          year 
ORDER  BY dept_id, 
          year
```

The data I got was:

[image]

Here there is no problem as my sql is running right.So, I needed to extract all the information of `col` table,So I used subquery as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   offc.col 
WHERE  ( dept_id, year, marks ) IN (SELECT dept_id, 
                                           year, 
                                           Max(marks) marks 
                                    FROM   offc.col 
                                    GROUP  BY dept_id, 
                                              year 
                                    ORDER  BY dept_id, 
                                              year);
```

But,I got error as:

```
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

i searched this error at other pages also,but I found them as bracket misplace error.But in my case,I dont know what is happening here?

Comment: The `IN` operator doesn't work like this. You can test a **single** value against a list or sub-query: `DEPT_ID IN (2, 5, 6)` or `DEPT_ID IN (SELECT id FROM ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of aggregating, you can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*
from offc.col c
where marks = (
    select max(marks)
    from offc.col c1
    where c1.dept_id = c.dept_id and c1.year = c.year
)
order by dept_id, year
```

An index on `(dept_id, year, marks)` would speed up this query.

Another option is to use window function `row_number()`:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        c.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by dept_id, year order by marks desc) rn
    from offc.col c
) x
where rn = 1
order by dept_id, year
```

---

If you *do want* to stick to aggregation, then you can join your subquery with the original table as follows:

```
select c.* 
from offc.col c
inner join (
    select dept_id, year, max(marks) marks 
    from offc.col 
    group  by dept_id, year 
) m 
    on m.dpt_id = c.dept_id
    and m.year = c.year
    and m.marks = m.marks
```

Comment: can u also help me with aggregating function? i am learning so i need basic core knowledge

Comment: @KarkiAshwin: the correlated subquery is core knowledge as well, and it usually gives better performance (and readability). Still, I updated my answer with a solution that uses aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use `dense_rank` analytical function as it can return two department if they have same marks in same year.(your current logic is same as this)

`Row_number` will give you only one random record if two department have same marks in same year.

```
select *
from (
    select 
        c.*, 
        dense_rank() over(partition by dept_id, year order by marks desc nulls last) as dr
    from offc.col c
) x
where dr = 1
order by dept_id, year
```

Also, your query is correct, just remove order by from it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   offc.col 
WHERE  ( dept_id, year, marks ) IN (SELECT dept_id, 
                                           year, 
                                           Max(marks) marks 
                                    FROM   offc.col 
                                    GROUP  BY dept_id, 
                                              year 
                                    -- ORDER  BY dept_id,                                              
                                -- year
);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=61783087060a508a842116b9a352a7a9) of error with `order by` and working fine without `order by`.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Perform an INNER JOIN with your subquery:

```
SELECT c.*
  FROM offc.col c
  INNER JOIN (SELECT dept_id, 
                     year, 
                     Max(marks) AS MAX_MARK
                FROM offc.col 
                GROUP BY dept_id, 
                         year) s
    ON s.DEPT_ID = c.DEPT_ID AND
       s.YEAR = c.YEAR AND
       s.MAX_MARK = c.MARKS
  ORDER BY c.DEPT_ID, c.YEAR
```

An INNER JOIN only returns rows where the join condition is satisfied so any rows in OFFC.COL which do not have the maximum value for MARKS for a particular DEPT_ID and YEAR will not be returned.